"Failed to retrieve share list from server" error in *corporate environment" when browsing a share with Nautilus
I re-ask the question but specifically in a corporate environment where users don't have access to their company's windows server configurations (that means, any company beyond a few staff).
I need to access company SMB shares from Ubuntu.
Here's what i tried:

the servers are pingable through their names, and I use names to access smb://[name]
nmap gives:  PORT    STATE    SERVICE

137/tcp filtered netbios-ns
138/tcp filtered netbios-dgm
139/tcp filtered netbios-ssn
445/tcp open     microsoft-ds

I set the protocol in smb.conf on NT1, SMB2, SMB3 (both cli+serv), to no avail.

Apparently there is some issue in gvfs preventing access:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/gvfs/+bug/1828107
It is a 5yo uncorrected issue, but I am not qualified on that.
Are there any #samba #gvfs #nautilus devs out there listening?
Whom to ask?
Is there any solution?
This is really crippling whole Ubuntu functionality. Accessing SMB shares is a BASIC function, not being able to do it is getting me in trouble.
Thanks for any help.

All the info in your question is Windows related. Off topic on this site. Is this not something you talk to your corporate IT about.

Please edit your post and provide the output of this command:  smbclient -L win-ip-address -U win-user-name with the correct windows ip address and user name.

Forgot to ask: Do you know what version of Windows the server is running?

Try Dolphin file manager, it uses kio-fuse instead of gvfs
